# How to derive a four-bit even function?

Tags: logic, hardware, circuit

My guess was F(x,y,z,w) = ((x XOR y) XOR (z XOR w))'

Is this right?

If so, can you explain why?

If not, how do you do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To figure out whether it's an even function, draw up a truth table. If the output is a 1 when an even number of inputs are 1, then it's an even function. Otherwise it's an odd function (since this is almost certainly homework, I'm not going to give a more direct answer than that).

If it's an odd function, you can typically get an even function by complementing the last gate, so your middle `xor` would be changed to an `xnor`.